# Maven needs extra dependency to build the project whereas Gradle doesn't

Tags: java, maven, gradle, javafx, jfoenix

I am currently learning [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) library. There is a nice [demo](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/tree/master/demo) and [instructions](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/wiki#trying-the-demo) how to run it.

JFoenix uses Gradle, but I need to use Maven, so I've decided to recreate the demo project using Maven for further testing.

The problem appeared when I tried to run my newly created project. It turned out that some classes (e.g. `de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon`) were not found. I found out that `de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-5` depends on `de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:8.15` in runtime. So I decided to add it as compile dependency and the demo ran correctly. But [build.gradle](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/demo/build.gradle) of the demo specifies only `de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-5`.

Do Maven and Gradle handle dependencies in a different way? Or is it a specific case?

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>jfoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- Bintray is needed for de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome. -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.datafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>datafx</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.datafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>flow</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx-fontawesome</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0-5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Without this dependency the project can't be compiled. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx-commons</artifactId>
            <version>8.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

P.S. I am not sure whether the title for this question is OK. So suggestions are welcome.

P.P.S. If you try to compile the demo using my `pom.xml` you'll have to comment out `demos.components.AnimationTemplateDemo.java` because `com.jfoenix.transitions.template` package is [new](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/commits/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/transitions/template) and is not available in `com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pom.xml file at jcenter is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
  <artifactId>fontawesomefx-fontawesome</artifactId>
  <version>4.7.0-5</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
      <artifactId>fontawesomefx-commons</artifactId>
      <version>8.15</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see, fontawesomefx-commons is only required at *runtime*. I’m not sure why this is, but it explains why it is not pulled at *compile* time.

I don’t now where gradle pulls its dependency from, you don’t mention it, but my guess is that the configuration there is not runtime, but compile.

---

**Edit** : the scope is **compile** at later versions of fontawesomefx-fontawesome. So it appears that the *runtime* scope specified in the 4.7.0-5 version is probably a bug…

**pom.xml for version 4.7.0-9:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
  <artifactId>fontawesomefx-fontawesome</artifactId>
  <version>4.7.0-9</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
      <artifactId>fontawesomefx-commons</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The link to the `build.gradle` of the demo is in my question. Here it is one again: https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/demo/build.gradle.
It's written `compile 'de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-5'`.

Comment: Ok, it looks clear now. Runtime scope for jcenter 4.7.0-5 was probably a mistake, corrected in later versions.

Comment: Thank for the edit.
It really seems like `runtime` scope is a bug.
But how does Gradle manages to build it correctly?..

Comment: in gradle, all that is runtime is also compile: https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management